# SPListItem update conflict

Tags: 2010, splistitem, splist, updatelistitems, unsafe-updates

Task: when user updates an item, change synchronously another hidden field of this item.
Problem: save conflict occurs AFTER update is called (not on this line).

- I subscribe on EventReceiver's `ItemUpdating` method
- I use SystemUpdate instead of Update.
- EventFiring is off
- AllowUnsafeUpdates is true

But I still get the same error. What is wrong with this code?...

```
    public void SyncTextFields()
    {        
        _listItem["Investigation_Exporter_Text"] = Exporter;
        _listItem.SystemUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Set the synchronization property in the eventbinder.xml file to Synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `SPItemEventProperties.AfterProperties` instead of inner SPListItem and it worked fine. Thanks for reply. I'l try to set Synchronous and check if it help.